# tampermonkey script stops working if I change the page

Tags: javascript, html, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I am using Tampermonkey to save time on frequent tasks. The goal is to get content of an element on www.example1.com, navigate to another page, and do stuff there. The starting page is www.example1.com as seen from `match`. This is the code I am using:

```
//@match  http://example1.com

var item = document.getElementById("myId").textContent;

window.open("http://example2.com","_self");

setTimeOut(function(
//perform clicks on this page
){},3000);
```

None of the code after changing URLs ever gets executed. Why, and what is the workaround?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Allow the userscript on both urls and use `GM_setValue`/`GM_getValue` to organize the communication.

```
//@match   http://example1.com
//@match   http://example2.com
//@grant   GM_getValue
//@grant   GM_setValue

if (location.href.indexOf('http://example1.com') == 0) {
    GM_setValue('id', Date.now() + '\n' + document.getElementById("myId").textContent);
    window.open("http://example2.com","_self");
} else if (location.href.indexOf('http://example2.com') == 0) {
    var ID = GM_getValue('id', '');
    if (ID && Date.now() - ID.split('\n')[0] < 10*1000) {
        ID = ID.split('\n')[1];
        .............. use the ID
    }
}
```

- This is a simplified example.  In the real code you may want to use `location.host` or `location.origin` or match `location.href` with regexp depending on what the real urls are.
- To pass complex objects serialize them:

  ```
  GM_setValue('test', JSON.stringify({a:1, b:2, c:"test"}));
  ```

  ```
  try { var obj = JSON.parse(GM_getValue('test')); }
  catch(e) { console.error(e) }
  ```

Comment: neat approach. I implemented it but I am getting an error:  GM_setValue is not defined.

Comment: Most likely you forgot to declare it in `@require` as shown in the answer.

Comment: Mind reading abilities you got there:D i did forget to declare it. I added the declaration but I am still getting the error. Is the order of declarations relevant?

Comment: Not `@require`. `@grant`.  Edited answer.